# having an or condition between two values

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an below xsl tag condtion as shown below ..

```
<xsl:for-each select="/abc/def">
            <xsl:if test="./Scheme='xxx' and ./Reference='TRE' and string(./tId)">
```

Now the change that i want to made in this condition is that is the  Reference value can be  `'TRE' or it can be 'ARE'`

so i want to go for both that is if it is coming as 'TRE' then it is also ok or if it is coming as 'ARE' then it is also ok so in other words i want an 'OR, condition between them please advise how to achieve this..

folks please advise

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:if test="Scheme='xxx' and (Reference='TRE' or Reference='ARE') and string(tId)">
```